# JQuery show label on hover of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to get a label to show when they hover over a Input field. Here is what my form looks like.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
            <div class="loginbox">
            <div class="box">
                <input runat="server" id="txt_clientrefmock2" class="logintextbox" placeholder="Client Ref" type="text" />
                <input runat="server" id="txt_postcodemock2" class="logintextbox" placeholder="Postcode" type="text" />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_dateofbirth" CssClass="logintextbox" />
                <AjaxControlToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_dateofbirth" Mask="99/99/9999" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="btnlogin">
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" CssClass="loginButton" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            </div>
            <div class="messages">
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Please contact 88888 888 888 if you cannot find your client reference" ID="message" Visible="false" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want to happen is when they hover over the Client Ref box then my label to become visible.

I have tried code like this (This isn't working):

```
    <script>
        $(".txt_clientrefmock2").hover(
          function () {
              $("#message").show();
          },
          function () {
              $("#message").hide();
          }
        );
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

I have found out the problem which leads to another similar problem.

When I took the "Visable = False" from the label and ran the code it works fine.

So how else can I hide the label on Page_Load?

Comment: `$('body').find('#message').show()`?

Comment: could you provide us the fiddle

Comment: Is the ID still actually set to `message` when it renders, or has asp.net changed it to something else?

Comment: Also, do you realise you've posted a phone number in the code...?

Comment: Are we code-debuggers on SO?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Is random I made it up :)

Comment: @pc-shooter Don't know you tell me.

Comment: @Ben ok - quick google shows it's a real one somewhere :)  Something to be aware of is that the [UK has a fictional number range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_telephone_number#United_Kingdom) much like '555' in the US

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ok thanks, I will delete it now. I have edited my post as I have sorta figured the issue, but not fully.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using ASP.NET and `txt_clientrefmock2` is a server control you need to use [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) and you are using ID so you need to use `#` for ID selector.

`<%= txt_clientrefmock2.ClientID %>` will Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

Use

```
$("#<%= txt_clientrefmock2.ClientID %>").hover(function() {
    $(".message").show(); //Here Message is a class so you need to use .
}, function() {
    $(".message").hide();
});
```

Comment: `#<%=`? Can you explain

Comment: Thanks thats help and moreover Im not the asp.net guy

Answer (score 1):

In your code `txt_clientrefmock2` is `ID` not a `class`. Update your code like below.

```
    $("#txt_clientrefmock2").hover(
      function () {
          $("#message").show();
      },
      function () {
          $("#message").hide();
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I just figured it out going through some of the comments.

When @James Thorpe mentioned about the ID changing when the page renders, I took out "Visable=False" from the label and ran my code.

When i hovered over the Input then it worked.

I replaced

```
Visable=False
```

With

```
style="display:none;"
```

This then worked. Thanks for all your help on the situation.

Comment: you could also put the following into your document(ready) function:
$("#message").hide();

thus on page load, the message gets hidden and will be shown on hover ...

i prefer this one, because the css "display: none" get's overridden by show(), if someone uses "visibilty:hidden" instead, show() won't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Doing Visible=false will not hide that thing . Hiding anything is done by display:none . If you are doing Visible=false ,then that thing would be present over there but not be actually seen .It's just you made it's visiblity false not hid that . And yes ofcourse , you have wrongly used the ids and classes in your syntax.